# Outgoing Skype message doesn't work with Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, skype

I had a Skype bot, but Microsoft upgraded API version from V1 to V3. I'm trying send message to myself, but it doesn't work. API always returns this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "message": "Resource not found"
}
```

The request URL is:

```
https://api.botframework.com/v3/conversations/29:16TaxVHUvlzyFDJpdJJ4NnadhxtLnqBgoNx8stAOmkJ8/activities

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJ****************(My Token)
Content-Type: application/json
```

Also you can find the error in [Postman Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMBLG.png).

What can I do to send message to a Skype user using Botframework?

Comment: 404 suggests the conversation does not exist. Are you sure you created it before sending the message? Are you sure you're using the right conversationId? Also, you're supposed to send an `Activity` object, that does not have a field called `message` (use `text` instead).

Comment: Thank you, but i'm fixed this replace API adress with "skype.botframework.com" and replace body to a Activity object.

Comment: Does your bot reflect V3 in the bot directory page.   in dev.botframework.com  under My Bots  > botname ,  there's a version number left hand column, under Bot Handle

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong endpoint.  You should use "skype.botframework.com" not "api.botframework.com".